# Custom View - Avoid redrawing when non-interactive

Tags: android, optimization, rendering

I have a complex custom view - photo collage.

What is observed is whenever any UI interaction happens, the view is redrawn.

How can I avoid complete redrawing (for example, use a cached UI) of the view specially when I click the "back" button to go back to previous activity because that also causes redrawing of the view.

While exploring the API and web, I found a method - `getDrawingCache()` - but don't know how to use it effectively.

How do I use it effectively?

I've had other issues with Custom Views that I outline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764371/android-custom-view-optimizing-redrawing-while-fling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way than using getDrawingCache.

In the method onDraw, apart from drawing in the natural canvas, I also draw on an memory-only canvas.

```
Bitmap cacheBmp = Bitmap.Create(....);
Canvas cacheCanvas = new Canvas(cacheBmp);


void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
   if(updateDueToInteraction)
   {
     c.drawXXX(...);
     cacheCanvas.drawXXX(...);
   } else
   {
     c.drawBitmap(cacheBmp, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to use the `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` method, so that you're View is cache-enabled. Then, you can use the [getDrawingCache(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)) method which returns a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) representing the View. Then, you can draw that bitmap manually.

If you don't enable caching by calling the `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` method, you will have to call `buildDrawingCache()` before (and call `destroyDrawingCache()` when you're done).

Bye!

Comment: Hi Casidiablo,

Thanks for your response.

It is advisable to have a cache like this in the scenario when the updates / refreshes are more frequent? Or will it be applicable to only when we know what needs to be shown - dynamic, but once defined that is it!